# What is the alternative of export from unix to powershell, Set works for CMD only. I need it for powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, set, export, django-settings

[powershell not working to set Django settings module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km5r5.png)

I failed to set-up and run my Django project using PowerShell, I can run and set Django Settings Module from CMD but the same thing is not working for Powershell.

Comment: Please post error messages _as text_, as a direct part of your question. Only uses images to supplement the information, if necessary, and make them render in-line rather than linking to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for it to be permanent use:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('var_name','var_value','MACHINE')
```

If you are looking for something you set at each run use:

```
$env:var_name = 'var_value'
```